# PHP mail() doesn't work since i have a server using SSL Email

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp

I have a PHP form simply using mail() function of PHP. After i changed my server emails to use SSL (Secure-SMTP,Secure-IMAP,Secure-POP) the form don't send emails to account@mydomain.com , I think it's because of the protocol changes and hope someone can help me with this.

Also I tried to use SMTP Authentication in my PHP codes using SSL (to see if it can solve my problem) but i don't know what is the included file at the first of this example: http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Comment: the included file is a php file from Pearl Mail package as far as I can tell: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you posted describes how to send mail with the Mail Pear library. So the 
require_once "Mail.php"; instruction simply loads this Pear library.
It assumes you have correctly installed it, see pear documentation.

Another good library for mail via php is phpmailer!

Comment: Is there another way to use this method without using PEAR Lib ?!

Comment: I don't think so. I seems that base php mail() function doesn't support smtp authentication with ssl like you need. I think you need mail library.

Comment: OK, i asked because i have a Linux cPanel\WHM server and i used some scripts like WHMCS before and they didn't asked me to install this lib. for SMTP authentication. Please let me know with this lib, the main problem will solve or not?

Comment: Sure: if you use for example phpmailer in your script you can connect to a SMTP server (also with ssl) and send e-mails. Look a this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835651/can-someone-help-me-out-with-phpmailer/7836307#7836307